# Define $\binom{\sin x}{x}$ and try to calculate an approximation of $\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients

I was playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) when I wondered how o define $$\binom{\sin x}{x}\tag{1}$$ in the integrand of $$\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{x}dx,\tag{2}$$ and how to calculate an approximation of such definite integral (isn't required a very good approximation, only an idea of how to calculate an approximation).
There were my codes

`Plot Binom(sin(x),x), from x=0 to pi`

`int Binom(sin(x),x)dx`

that provide us a series expansion of the integral at $x=0$, and finally

`int Binom(sin(x),x)dx, from x=0 to pi`

> **Question.** Please define/expain me the integrand $(1)$ and calculate an approximation of $$\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{x}dx.$$ 
>   **Many thanks.**

Comment: As was said isn't required a very good approximation, and if your answer use a numerical method, is required some details about how it works with our integrand (how is defined the integrand). Many thanks.

Comment: $${a\choose b}=\dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$
with $a!=\Gamma(a+1)$

Comment: Many thanks for the definition @MyGlasses , I hope that it is convergent!

Comment: Did I get that right: you typed something into Wolfram Alpha you don't understand, and ask now how Wolfram Alpha understood it, and how it calculated a result like $1.36198436192469512976009376775456704074252675\ldots$?

Comment: Good morning @ProfessorVector I did not even understand the definition of the integrand of my integral. I do not ask about how the mentioned CAS does the calculations, that I am asking is the definition of the integrand and a method (theoretical using real analysis or well using numerical analysis) that provide us an approximation (
I'm interested in knowing a method that gives us a few correct digits, 3 or 4).

Comment: @ProfessorVector today I was calculating different kind of integrals: for example the case $n=2$ of $\int_0^1\binom{x}{n} \left\{ \frac{1}{x}\right\}dx$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start on the definition of the integrated function. It just requires a careful application of known facts:

$$\binom{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\Gamma(1+\sin x)}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1+\sin x-x)}$$

To deal with the denominator, we use the known reflection formula:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)}=\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}$$

---

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)}=\frac{-\sin \pi x}{\pi} \Gamma(-x)$$

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\sin x-x)}=\frac{-\sin \pi (x-\sin x)}{\pi} \Gamma(x-\sin x)$$

Now we use the main definition of the Gamma function to show how all this works together:

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt$$

---

> $$\binom{\sin x}{x}= -\frac{\sin \pi x ~\sin \pi (x-\sin x)}{\pi^2} \times \\ \times \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty ~ \frac{w^{x}}{v^{x}}~ \frac{u^{\sin x}}{w^{\sin x}} \frac{e^{-u-v-w}}{v w}~ du~dv~dw $$

This is quite complicated, but now nothing prevents you from integrating w.r.t. $x$ now right inside this triple integral (unless some problems with convergence are involved).

---

Unrelated to the previous, but worthy of note. Changing $x \to \pi-x$ we have:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{x}dx=\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{\pi-x}dx$$

Another relation follows from the properties of binomial coefficients:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{x}dx=\int_0^{\pi}\binom{1+\sin x}{1+x}dx-\int_0^{\pi}\binom{\sin x}{1+x}dx$$

We can continue this recursion if we want. This actually helps us deal with some of the numerical issues arising in the original integral when $x$ is close to $0$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.